# Having a 100% height for an empty div

Tags: css, html

Yes I have seen dozens of question regarding 100% div. But I still cant implement it. 
since I am using a negative margin on the right div.

The test version is here:http://bazarak.af/t.php

If I remove the height key from the spiral class then the metal spiral is not appeared. 
Please somebody help me. I just want the spiral to appear alongside the content.

I could use javascript but not everybody has javascript enabled.

Since im going to remove the test page when the problem is solved so here is the code for others:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>TEST</title>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper{
margin: 0px auto; 
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
width: 1030px;
}

body{
background-color: #f3f0e6;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.content{
float: left;
width: 960px;
padding: 15px;
}

.spiral { 
float: right;
margin-right: -32px;

width:63px; 
height: 500px;

background-image:url(images/home/spiral.jpeg);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:top left;
}

.clear{clear: both;}
</style>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="spiral"></div><!-- END SPIRAL -->
        <div class="content">

        [HEADER]</br></br></br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</br></br></br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</br></br></br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</br></br></br></br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</br></br></br></br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</br></br></br></br> [FOOTER]

        </div><!-- END CONTENT -->
        <div class="clear"/>
    </div><!-- END WRAPPER -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's JavaScript, not Java ;) Two very different languages.

Comment: You are right. sorry. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer based on my comment.

jsfiddle.net/kxwgJ/1

I simply removed the "float" from the spiral container and just absolutely positioned it.  Since the spiral is just a design and it's being positioned relative to it's parent, absolute positioning seems to make more sense and you can avoid some issues with floats.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But please next time do not upload somebody elses image on another server. You did not have the permission to do this. But its my fault. I hadn't write any copyright notes. However, you solution was awesome and the site works great now. :)

Comment: Point taken about the image.  That thought never actually crossed my mind.  I'll have to be more mindful of it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `display: table-cell;`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RZBAg/

(The HTML markup changes a bit, since the spiral comes *after* the content. I also added a red background to illustrate the size of the spiral div.)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I did the same thing but I changed the "float" to "position:absolute;" http://jsfiddle.net/kxwgJ/1/  I also shrank the notebook to 200px to make it easier to view in jsFiddle. =)

Comment: Make sure it works outside of jsfiddle, because it needs a height in order to expand and jsfiddle has a height defined in a parent.

Comment: @jeremyharris, Thank you for your time. But the spiral ended up inside the wrapper gray border.  @ jmbertucci Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. It works with such a beauty. Thank you both of you. Have a great day.